# Not matching is not NoneType condition in Python

Tags: python

I m having problem with these piece of code.

```
if tdinst[0].string in features:
       nameval=tdinst[0].string
       value=tdinst[1].string
       print type(value)
       if type(value) is not None:
               print"it should not come here"
              value=value.replace("\n","")
              value=value.replace("\t","")
```

I m getting **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'**.Why is it going inside second if condition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a difference between `NoneType` and `None`.

You need to be checking

```
if type(value) != NoneType:
```

or

```
if value is not None:
```

but perhaps the following is more straightforward:

```
if tdinst[0].string in features:
    nameval = tdinst[0].string
    value = tdinst[1].string
    if value: # this is also False if value == "" (no need to replace anything)
        value = value.replace("\n","").replace("\t","")
```

or, if `tdinst[1].string` *is* not `None` in the majority of cases, then exception handling is faster:

```
try:
    value = tdinst[1].string.replace("\n","").replace("\t","")
except TypeError:
    value = None
```

Comment: i am trying to scrape a website.And only some pages have value others are empty and i m trying to filter it this way..

Comment: is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @vindhya -- You could probably just do `if value: ...`

Answer (score 4):

There is no such type as `None`. You probably meant `NoneType`:

```
if type(value) is not NoneType:
```

But why are you testing against `type`? Just check for `value`:

```
if value is not None:
```